# Way to convert execute_query Result set in cx_oracle 7.2.1

Tags: python, cx-oracle

We are trying to migrate our app from cx oracle into session pool session, but seems there is a difference in the return pool for the execute query.

The cx oracle version is 7.2.1

Is there a way to convert the result into a list of Records or List of Set/Dict?

Using Normal Session, the return is **list of Record**.
Using Session Pool, the return is **list of tuple**.

Here is the code for the query in normal session

```
def execute_query(self, sql_query, parameters=None):
        if parameters is None:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_query)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_query, parameters)

        result = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return result
```

Here is the code for the query in session pool

```
def execute_query(self, sql_query, parameters=None):
        if parameters is None:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_query)
            self.cursor.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip([d[0].lower() for d in self.cursor.description], args))
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_query, parameters)
            self.cursor.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip([d[0].lower() for d in self.cursor.description], args))

        result = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return result
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not use the same `rowfactory` line in both cases? (Or not use in both cases if you want the standard records-as-tuples output.)

Comment: I want to make the output in session pool as same normal session to minimize code changes, which is list of Records

Comment: For statement execution there's no inherent different between a standalone connection and a pooled connection.  Review your code and make sure your testing was clean.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my solution is using `sqlalchemy` and `cx_Oracle`,
use `sqlalchemy` create connect `session` and execute sql cmd:

```
result = self.session.execute(sql_cmd)
return [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in result]
```